# How to get video audio stream using ffmpeg pipe fdkaac m4a?

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, mkv, stream, m4a

I want final file as .mkv containing video stream copy and audio stream encoded by fdkaac bt unfortunately i only get audio file pls help me how to pipe video stream also here???

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec -f wav - | fdkaac -p 2 -m 0  -a 1 - -o "test.mkv"
```

Answer (score 1):

## ffmpeg + fdkaac

`fdkaac` is only an audio encoder. You can have `fdkaac` encode the audio, then re-mux with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -f wav - | fdkaac -p 2 -m 0  -a 1 - -o audio.m4a
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i audio.m4a -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mkv
```

## ffmpeg by itself

An alternative method is to compile `ffmpeg` with libfdk_aac support. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu Compile Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) for detailed instructions. Then you can do it all in one command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a libfdk_aac output.mkv
```

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.mkv -f wav - | fdkaac -p 2 -m 0  -a 1 - -o audio.m4a
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i audio.m4a -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mkv

problem in this is that if mkv file audio has DELAY in it that our final mkv mux file is out of sync ...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chrisvaughn/469312639631a65798c70acef36a108e

i am able to compile with fdkaac using this but than problem is this not support HEVC_Nvenc or h264_cuvid

Comment: @Amitthakur I suggest asking a new question because nvenc support is a completely different topic. This answer is directly addressing the fdk question.